# Different results when using SUM and not?

Tags: excel

Does anyone know why Excel gives different answers to the same question when using SUM function or not?

If you type in:

```
=0.1+0.1+0.1-0.3
```

You get a different (correct) response of `0` compared to:

```
=SUM(0.1+0.1+0.1-0.3)
```

Which gives an incorrect answer of `5.55112E-17`.

I understand that Excel uses the IEEE 754 and that explains why the second is off, but what I would like to know is how the two differ, and what does the first do to get it correct?

Comment: Your first formula uses `-3` whereas your `SUM` formula contains `-0.3`...

Comment: Testing it out, I believe he meant `-0.3` in the first formula too, one equates to 0 and the other equates to `5.55112E-17`.

Comment: I've edited the question. It's actually quite intriguing now, and my facetious answer is no longer valid.

Comment: seems to be the same as parameters too `=SUM(0.1+0.1+0.1-0.3)=SUM(0.1,0.1,0.1,-0.3)`

Comment: @Jeeped: We know that. I have to head out now sadly but the answer is to do with where a constant expression is evaluated by Excel on its calc cycle.

Comment: It appears to be a floating point error.

Comment: @Jeeped , agreed. [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel) may help OP understand why it's happening.

Comment: Excel usually rounds numbers to [15 significant digits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/269370/last-digits-are-changed-to-zeroes-when-you-type-long-numbers-in-cells-of-excel), so the `E-17` in the result is a sign that it should be rounded. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214118/how-to-correct-rounding-errors-in-floating-point-arithmetic

Comment: @Bathsheba & Jordan. Thanks for the edits and interest. I was writing it in a rush and it wasn't as clear as it should have been.

Comment: just to confirm, the solution is to round up to 15 significant digits in the cases that are not rounded `=ROUND(SUM(0.1+0.1+0.1-0.3),15)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is taken from [Microsoft's page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel) explaining floating-point arithmetic:

---

> **Example when a value reaches zero**
>
> In Excel 95 or earlier, enter the following into a new workbook:
>
> ```
> A1: =1.333+1.225-1.333-1.225
> ```
>
> Right-click cell A1, and then click Format Cells. On the Number tab,
>   click Scientific under Category. Set the Decimal places to 15. Instead
>   of displaying 0, Excel 95 displays -2.22044604925031E-16.
>
> Excel 97, however, introduced an optimization that attempts to correct
>   for this problem. Should an addition or subtraction operation result
>   in a value at or very close to zero, Excel 97 and later will
>   compensate for any error introduced as a result of converting an
>   operand to and from binary. The example above when performed in Excel
>   97 and later correctly displays 0 or 0.000000000000000E+00 in
>   scientific notation.

---

It appears as though the optimization mentioned in the last paragraph is not applied if brackets are included in the calculation - perhaps it disrupts the calculation sequence. For example:

```
=0.1+0.1+0.1-0.3 = 0
```

However:

```
=(0.1+0.1+0.1-0.3) = 5.551115123125780E-17
```

Yet, the miscalculation is not only applicable to those numbers in brackets but also the numbers outside, provided there are brackets in the formula. So:

```
=0.1+0.1+0.1-0.3+(0.1+0.1+0.1-0.3) = 1.110223024625160E-16
```

This calculation gives twice the error in it's calculation despite the first part not being parenthesised.

Comment: to add to the test cases, `=(0.5-0.4-0.1)` and `=1-1+(0.5-0.4-0.1)` are off, but `=0.5-0.4-0.1` and `=(0.5-0.4-0.1)+1` are correct

Comment: @Jordan Thanks for your response. I have marked it as correct. In short I was attributing the error to the SUM fuction when in fact it was due to the use of brackets. This is strange stuff from Excel. Looks like it could do with further optimisations.