# Why does parenthesis make a difference?

Tags: excel, precision

I have this weird issue. The setup is simple:

- I have a value (51,8) in cell D13
- I have 12 cells (E13:P13) with formula "=$D$13"
- Q13 is average of E13:P13 (formula AVG/AVERAGE)

The problem is:

- When I make a formula "=Q13-D13" I get 0,000 (continues with 0). This is OK and as expected
- But when I use a parenthesis in the formula, "=(Q13-D13)", I get a small negative value, -0,000000000000007105427358..." This is nok OK and highly unexpected, and I have never seen this before

Comment: Apparently, adding parenthesis makes Excel store the subtraction result as an intermediate value in a single-precision floating-point register, causing the loss of precision in the value, while the same does not happen with a direct subtraction (where it might be using the x86 extended 80-bits precision, but that's speculation). You will observe the same loss of precision if you change the formula to `Q13-D13+0`. Note that this is not a simple display issue: comparing the results with `=` will show they're really not equal, with one being precisely zero and the other one not.

Comment: Actually, scratch that whole bit about the x86 register -- it's more likely it's to do with when Excel chooses to round values that are very close to 0 down to 0, even though internally they're not. This "fix" was introduced in Excel 97, but can cause even more confusion than the original precision limitation. [See also](https://support.microsoft.com/help/78113/).

Comment: @kabanus not a dupe of that at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different results when using SUM and not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491362/different-results-when-using-sum-and-not)

Comment: @AakashM retracted, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. They made some things more clear. I am still puzzled, thoug. The values only have one decimal, so in my mind 15 decimals og floating point should never be an issue...

Comment: The values are not stored as decimals, they're stored as binary floating-point. This means the actual number of decimals is irrelevant: a value like `0.2` can be represented exactly in base 10, but not in base 2. Likewise, the closest value to `51.8` is actually more like `51.79999999999999716...` (when converted from binary back to decimals). The "15 decimals" are just the number of decimals that can be safely stored without losing them. This is also why many systems that deal with financial calculations use base 10 floating point to avoid these problems -- not Excel, though.

Comment: Try the same exercise with a value that does have an exact representation, like `51.875`. Even though it has "more decimals", the very tiny difference between the average and the original value disappears.